# Yii phpmailer not working for gmail

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I'm using `Yii phpmailer` extension to send mail using `gmail` but it showing `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.` instead of sending mail. My code what I used

```
    Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
    $mail = new JPhpMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    //$mail->Host = 'smpt.163.com';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.googlemail.com:465';
    //$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com:587';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Username = $email;
    $mail->Password = $pass;
    $mail->SetFrom($email, SiteConfig::SITE_TITLE);
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication';
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
    $mail->MsgHTML('<h1>JUST A TEST!</h1>');
    $mail->AddAddress($email, 'My Name');
    $mail->Send();
```

I followed this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/).

How can I solve this problem and send mail using gmail? I’d appreciate any light you can shed on this!!

Comment: It might help to know what happens (if anything) when that code is run?

Comment: The link you should follow is [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Almost certainly a well known gmail auth issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line:

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

I am unsure if adding `:port` works for the Host field as you've done - I can confirm that setting the `Port` field manually does work, as I have a large system whose code looks very similar to yours which is working as expected.

We also use `$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'` but I am almost certain that the `smtp.googlemail.com` domain should also work.

Comment: The Host property does work like that. You can also set the SMTPSecure option in there too, like `Host = 'tls://smtp.google.com:587'`

Comment: @Synchro thanks for clarifying that. In that case we need to know what output he's getting from SMTPDebug to have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug and get error report

for 1 error and message
for 2 message only

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
```

Comment: showing this message: SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP 22sm3212537pfh.48 - gsmtp

Comment: You need to enforce access to less secure apps from link. less secure apps setting or if you have configured email from google mail apps then go to admin->security->basic setting and do the above.  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the following attributes:

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure =  "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username =  "your username";
$mail->Password = "your password";
```

It should work with those attributes set.

Hope it helps.